# Silverstripe: Top.PageControllerFunction not displaying

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I am using the Silverstripe Twitter module. It has a page controller function called `LatestTweets($value)` Which obviously displays the latest tweets.

When I add the Latest Tweets function to the `Page.ss` template. The tweets display. Everything works fine.

I am also using shaedawson's blocks module. I have a 'grid' block. The Grid Block has a template (`Grid.ss`) In the Templates Folder (`templates/`). When I add `$Top.LatestTweets(3)` to the Grid Template, the tweets do not appear.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The reason why the "Latest Tweets" function was not appearing on my template, was because I had to extend `Block_Controller`

I added the following to my 'extension.yml' file:

```
Block_Controller:
  extensions:
    - TwitterExtension
```

I would like to be able to 'include' the "Twitter Feed" template in my Grid Template. However this works and will do for now.

Answer (score 2):

It works on any page controller, because the module `tractorcow/silverstripe-twitter` enables extension `TwitterExtension` on the `Page_Controller` in its configuration.

Blocks in `sheadawson/silverstripe-blocks` module are rendered with SiteTree context (the top scope) and your `LatestTweets()` function is not available.

So, the only remedy is to enable the `TwitterExtension` on your `Page`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I actually figured out how to fix this. I added an Extension to "Block Controller" in my extensions.yml file. 

`Block_Controller:

  extensions:

     - TwitterExtension`

And this worked.